# Updating state values from different screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, state

Very new to ReactNative.
Please let me know if I'm doing something unproperly.

On Screen A, I have a interval that handle a REST request and updates my Screen A state and its components.
Working fine so far!

To navigate to Screen B
`this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {state: this.state});`
and I'm using that state values to mount ScreenB components.

Even with ScreenB showing, at some point ScreenA interval updates my ScreenA state with new data.
What is the proper way to pass these new data to ScreenB state and update its components?

I thought passing state on navigation props would keep the same object (state) on all screens, but this is apparently wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add a common state management library like redux and use it across your screens. Once you have updated the data in one screen, you can dispatch an action to update the store. The page2 which is now showing will consume the change and rerender the new data changes.